# UI-SREF not working inside _layout.cshtml

Tags: css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am building a web application where I have only two states viz. Result and Queue. When my Result state is active I want it to be highlighted similarly for my Queue state as well. I am placing the UI-SREF in my _layout.cshtml. For some reason it is not working as it should work.

I tried ui-sref inside my State pages it is working.

Below is my _layout.cshtml

```
    **_layout.cshtml**

    <div class="menuBar">

    <span class="applicationName">Results Review Application</span>

    <span  ui-sref="Queue" ui-sref-active-eq="activeState">Queue</span>
    <span  ui-sref="Result" ui-sref-active-eq="activeState">Result</span>
</div>
```

Below is my routing code:

```
    (function () {
angular.module('resultReview')
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('Result', {
        url: '/Result',
        templateUrl: 'ResultReview/ResultPage'
    })
    .state('Queue', {
        url: '/Queue',
        templateUrl: 'ResultReview/ReviewTable'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Queue');
}]);
```

})()

I want the style of the span element to change when the state changes

Below is my css code for the class "activeState"

```
   .activeState {
background-color:white;
text-decoration:underline;
```

}

Any help in this regard is appreciated

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I am following to resolve the issue is that I am including the ngApp directive at the html tag of my _layout.cshtml.

Doing that resolved my issue.

Hope it helps others like me.